# Is it possible to solve vector equations?

Tags: vector

For example if we define parametric line segment

```
curve1[t_, p1_, p2_] := t*p2 + (1 - t)*p1;
```

where `p1` and `p2` are 2D vectors, we can draw it easily

```
p1 = {0, 0}; p2 = {1, 2}; ParametricPlot[curve1[t, p1, p2], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

But can't solve in general form

```
Clear[p1, p2]
Solve[curve1[t, p1, p2] == curve1[u, q1, q2], {t, u}]
```

because Mathematica treats `p1`, `p2`, `q1` and `q2` as scalars, and gives

$\left\{\left\{u\to -\frac{t (\text{p2}-\text{p1})}{\text{q1}-\text{q2}}-\frac{\text{p1}-\text{q1}}{\text{q1}-\text{q2}}\right\}\right\}$

Can I treat them as vectors and solve analytically?

Comment: @DanielHuber of course not, if `p1`, `p2`, `q1` and `q2` are all different, it doesn't true.

Comment: Sorry I read  it too fast.

Comment: This may be a starting point: `Reduce[curve1[t, p1, p2] == curve1[u, q1, q2] && (p1 | p2 | q1 | q2) ∈ Vectors[2, Reals], {t, u}]`

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Vectors`.

```
Solve[curve1[t, p1, p2] == curve1[u, q1, q2] && (p1 | p2 | q1 | q2) ∈ Vectors[2, Reals] && (t|u) ∈ Reals, {t, u}] //FullSimplify
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear[p1, p2]
curve1[t_, p1_, p2_] := t*p2 + (1 - t)*p1;
{p1, p2, q1, q2} = {{p1x, p1y}, {p2x, p2y}, {q1x, q1y}, {q2x, q2y}};
Solve[curve1[t, p1, p2] == curve1[u, q1, q2], {t, u}]
```

[image]

Comment: It's cheating :) Can I just tell solver, that some variables are vectors?

Comment: How do you know that it can be written without respect to the vector components?